# continuous function of the approximation of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264066/evaluating-the-factorial-related-limit-lim-x-to-infty-x-11-x-1#1264080) the top answer there uses some facts unknown to me.

First they seem to use

> $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow
> \infty} \frac{c_n}{d_n} = 1$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n + c_n =
> \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n + d_n$ if either limit exists.

My proof: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_n + c_n) - (b_n + d_n) = \log \left( \lim_{n
\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} \cdot \frac{c_n}{d_n} \right) = \log (1) =
0$, taking logs are valid since there is some $N$ s.t. when $n > N$ we have
$\frac{a_n}{b_n} > 0, \frac{c_n}{d_n} > 0$.

Is this (and the statement) correct?

Also, what about the more general:

> If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{i, n}}{b_{i, n}} = 1$ for $i = 1,
> \ldots, m$, then for continuous $g$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{g
> (a_1, \ldots, a_m)}{g (b_1, \ldots, b_m)} = 1$

This is true if the limits for each sequence exist, but what if they don't?

Comment: @SolidSnake Indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(I leave this as an answer so this question doesn't stay without an answer)**

It's easy to see that your generalization doesn't hold: $m=1$, $a_n=n$, $b_n=n+1$, $g(x)=2^x$.

About your proof, it looks more than good to me, moreover, one may think that it suffices that the limit of the $a_n/b_n$ and the limit of $c_n/d_n$ are positive and multiplicative inverses to conclude the same!.

Comment: I don't think positivity is required.

Comment: You need to ensure that $\log \left(\frac{a_n}{b_n} \cdot \frac{c_n}{d_n} \right)$is always defined.

Comment: But it is for large enough n since they are multicative inverses.

Comment: Right! That product must be positive eventually. Nice observation Simon! so yes, positive is not a necessary condition.