# continuous function of the approximation of a sequence 2

Tags: real-analysis

A followup on my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264144/continuous-function-of-the-approximation-of-a-sequence), does the following hold? Should make things simpler for powers instead of just addition.

> If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow
> \infty} \frac{c_n}{d_n} = 1$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g (a_n, c_n) =
> \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g (b_n, d_n)$ if either limit exists for continuous $g$.

Not sure how to prove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing a hypothesis, it's false. Let $g:(0,+\infty)\times(0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R},\ \ (x,y)\mapsto x^y$

Let 
$$\begin{cases}a_n=\left(1+{1\over n}\right)\\
b_n=1\\
c_n=d_n=n\end{cases}$$

$\lim_ng(a_n,c_n)=e\neq1=\lim_ng(b_n,d_n)$